# Difficulties in plotting a simple function which is convolution of a Gaussian and exponential decay

Tags: python, scipy, data-analysis, curve-fitting

I am trying to define a function and plot it. It is a convolution of a Gaussian (i) and exponential decay (f). It works fine for some x values but doesn't work for others. Can someone please help me find out why?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 16
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 5)

#d is FWHM of the Gaussian (determines the width of convolution)
#but the initial height and shape is affected by k value

def one_exp_fit_function(t1, d, u, k1):
    d_bar = d/(2*np.sqrt(np.log(2)))
    i = ((d_bar*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))**(-1))*np.exp(-np.log(2)*(((2*(t1-u))/d)**2))
    f = np.exp(-(k1)*t1)
    k = np.convolve(i, f, mode='same')
    return k

plt.plot(one_exp_fit_function(np.linspace(-5, 5, 100), 0.1, 3, 0.5), label='d=0.1, u=3, k=0.5')
plt.legend()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eayi.png)

But when I enter the following list as x values it returns a list of zeros.

```
one_exp_fit_function(x, 5, 908, 0.5)
```

output

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      dtype=float32)
```

This is my list of x values

x

907.6, 907.61, 907.62, 907.63, 907.64, 907.65, 907.66, 907.67, 907.68, 907.69, 907.7, 907.71, 907.72, 907.73, 907.74, 907.75, 907.76, 907.77, 907.78, 907.79, 907.8, 907.81, 907.82, 907.83, 907.84, 907.85, 907.86, 907.87, 907.88, 907.89, 907.9, 907.91, 907.92, 907.93, 907.94, 907.95, 907.96, 907.97, 907.98, 907.99, 908.0, 908.01, 908.02, 908.03, 908.04, 908.05, 908.06, 908.07, 908.08, 908.09, 908.1, 908.11, 908.12, 908.13, 908.14, 908.15, 908.16, 908.17, 908.18, 908.19, 908.2, 908.21, 908.22, 908.23, 908.24

Can someone please help me as to what the problem might be?

Comment: with such large `t1` value your `f = np.exp(-(k1)*t1)` will be almost 0

Comment: `exp(-r)` [underflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow) to 0.0 for `r` greater than about 745.